# Access local variables in superclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, constructor-chaining

I have a super class that has this constructor:

```
public Super(String p){
    String[] result = p.split(",");
    setA(result[0]);
    setB(result[1]);
    setC(result[2]);
    setD(result[3]);
    setE(result[4]);
}
```

Then I have a subclass, where I want to use the same constructor, but add 2 more strings. This is my code:

```
public Sub(String d){
    super(d);
    setF(result[5]);
    setG(result[6]);
}
```

Using this code I get an error that result is not specified. How can I fix this?

Comment: Scope it to the class rather than the constructor.

Comment: in super class or in sub class?

Comment: @tnw: As per my comments to Andremoniy, if this isn't logically state of the instance after construction, why would you want to make it a field? It's a really nasty design smell.

Comment: Calling methods in a constructor is also generally a code smell.   This could be a good candidate for a factory method that returns `Super` or `Sub` as appropriate, passing the individual arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, it was just a guess based off the info given. I don't disagree, but apparently this is what OP needed based on the accepted answer below. I like yours a lot better though.

Comment: Dear @Minde, could you please **unaccept** my answer, I want to delete it

Comment: @tnw: Well, my guess is that the OP accepted the answer without reading the arguments around it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you'd need to do the split again in the subclass constructor - the local variable `result` isn't available in the subclass constructor:

```
public Sub(String d){
    super(d);
    String[] result = d.split(",");
    setF(result[5]);
    setG(result[6]);
}
```

Yes, it'll end up duplicating work, but that's somewhat hard to avoid. You could do so by having a private subclass constructor which takes a `String[]`, and a factory method to do the split first:

```
protected Super(String[] result) {
    setA(result[0]);
    setB(result[1]);
    setC(result[2]);
    setD(result[3]);
    setE(result[4]);
}

protected Super(String d) {
    this(d.split(","));
}

...
private Sub(String[] result) {
    super(result);
    setF(result[5]);
    setG(result[6]); 
}

public static Sub fromString(String d) {
    return new Sub(d.split(","));
}
```

There's an alternative option where the superclass constructor calls a virtual method which is overridden in the subclass, but that's *really* fragile and it sufficiently horrible that I'm not even going to provide an example.

Comment: Not a very efficient idea, it will be spliited twice

Comment: @Andremoniy: I'd rather do that than have extraneous state in a class. I've now included an alternative approach.

Comment: Well, you want to say, that creating additional methods --and static Class --is mush more better then one more state in object?

Comment: @Andremoniy: Absolutely. Not sure what you mean by "and static Class" though. I've created alternative constructors and a static method. That has almost zero cost per object... whereas you're introducing extra space used in every single object created, for no good reason. Any time you've got a field which is *only* used in a constructor, that's a nasty design smell. I'd probably just take the small time hit of splitting twice though, unless I found that to be a problem.

Comment: "and static Class" was my mistake, forget it

Comment: Thank you, this way is much better